# Jenkins Batch-With-Multiple-Tests failure

Tags: jenkins

Our Jenkins reports a test failure `com.example.Batch-With-Multiple-Tests.testFoo`, with failure message "Forked Java VM exited abnormally. Please note the time in the report does not reflect the time until the VM exit." How do I actually find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that one of our automated tests was providing invalid configuration to the System Under Test (SUT), causing the SUT to terminate (i.e., call `System.exit()`), which is why the "Java VM exited abnormally".

The good news is that Jenkins provides a clue as to the location of the problem: the method name (`testFoo`). We happened to have only one class with a method named `testFoo`. In our case the problem was actually in the class initialization, but Jenkins attributed the problem to that class's first test method.